# Quick Adjustment to Outlook Macro Script

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros, microsoft-outlook-2016

The following Outlook macro works perfectly, however, I would like this MsgBox to only appear if the **Subject** is LIKE 'Fees Due%' OR Subject is LIKE'Status Change%'. Is this possible? @thims

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If MsgBox("Do you want to continue sending the mail?", vbOKCancel) <> vbOK Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your If MsgBox ... with the following:

```
If InStr(Item.Subject, "Fees Due") = 1 Or InStr(Item.Subject, "Status Change") = 1 Then
    ...
End If
```